# How do I hide the body field in a node using hide()?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using the following code, and it simply does not work:

```
 <?php hide($content['body']);
 print render($page['content']); ?>
```

I would like to hide the body field to show it elsewehere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're rendering the wrong thing: you need to render `$content`:

```
hide($content['body']);
print render($content);
```

See core's implementation of [`node.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7/source) for more information.